# remove default text from asp textbox using onfocus and onblur

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onfocus

I have tried to do this however it doesn't seem to work.  Below is my code.  When the textbox gains focus the color changes to yellow but the default text remains.  If I clear the text and lose focus then the textbox displays "undefined" in gray text.  Ultimately I would like the default text to be gray and the input text upon focus to be black.  Also, I would like to change the background color of the textbox upon focus.  Any advice would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" value="Enter Last Name" onfocus="gotFocus(this)" onblur="lostFocus(this)" Width="175px" CssClass="textbox1"></asp:TextBox>
```

**CSS**

```
.textbox1 {
            color:gray;
        }
```

**Javascript**

```
function gotFocus(obj)
{
    if (obj.value == obj.defaultvalue)
        obj.value = "";

    obj.style.color = "black";
    obj.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function lostFocus(obj)
{
    if (obj.value == "")
    {
        obj.value = obj.defaultvalue;
        obj.style.color = "gray";
    }

    obj.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the defaultvalue?

Comment: Have you heard of the [placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder) property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need JS, you can easily accomplish your requirement via. `CSS`

```
#TextBox1{
    color:grey; //or any color you want
}
#TextBox1:focus{
    color:white;
    background-color:black;//any color you want
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dqfLL/)

Comment: Thank you so much that makes it much nicer.  What does the # mean versus say "." (#Textbox vs .Textbox)  ????

Comment: # stands for id attribute whereas . is for class

Answer (score 1):

its easy fella:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" placeholder="default value"  Width="175px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

### IE 10 and above

**placeholder** is a good choice if you do not care about IE 9 and below.

[Can I use placeholder?](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder)

### IE 8 and 9

If you still need to take care of IE 8 and 9, you might want to look at -

[AjaxControlToolKit's TextBoxWatermark](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with CSS, don't use Javascript.

```
#TextBox1 { /* default style */
    color: grey;
}

#TextBox1:focus { /* style to apply on focus */
    color: black;
    background: /* some color */;
}
```